# Spring Boot REST force response type / 401 custom page not working?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm using Spring Boot 2.2.0.RELEASE to build my REST api.

I've managed to customize the 500/400/404 error pages (if somebody navigates with a browser) with thymeleaf and putting the files in:

```
src/main/resources/templates/error.html
src/main/resources/templates/errors/400.html
src/main/resources/templates/errors/404.html
```

All this works fine.

I noticed however, when somebody navigates to say /myrestapi in a browser, they get a 401 error. By default in Spring they would get a 403 error, but I have overridden that behavior to make it all 401s:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // return HTTP 401 instead of HTTP 403 for unauthorized requests

    http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint());
}

private AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint() {
    BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint basicAuthenticationEntryPoint = new BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint();
    basicAuthenticationEntryPoint.setRealmName("Bearer realm=\"oauth2-resource\"");
    return basicAuthenticationEntryPoint;
}
```

So I added:

```
src/main/resources/templates/errors/401.html
```

This doesn't seem to be getting picked up and when I go to the browser, it shows XML:

```
<oauth>
<error_description>
Full authentication is required to access this resource
</error_description>
<error>unauthorized</error>
</oauth>
```

When I go to that URL through Fiddler, it gives me Json, but I want the human to get my custom 401 page. I found some documentation that I need to do this:

WebSecurityConfig.java:

```
    http.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/resources/templates/errors/401.html")
                            .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint());
```

My ResourceServerConfig.java looks like this:

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // default behavior is to allow anonymous access unless @PreAuthorize is specified

http.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/resources/templates/errors/401.html").and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest()
                .permitAll();
```

}

But that doesn't work either.

Am I missing something?

NOTE: I am letting all requests through with permitAll() and then control OAuth access at the METHOD LEVEL using @PreAuthorize. But I also tried removing the permitAll() and its still not hitting.

Also tried the accessDeniedHandler and that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your path is wrong.
It should be /resources/templates/errors/401.html

Comment: Ooops… C&P typo. I have updated the post with some additional info.

Comment: Also using Swagger if that makes a difference.